# Memory and time issues when dividing two matrices

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I have two sparse matrices in matlab

M1 of size 9thousandx1.8million and M2 of size 1.8millionx1.8million.

Now I need to calculate the expression

```
M1/M2
```

and it took me like an hour. Is it normal? Is there any efficient way in matlab so that I can overcome this time issue. I mean it's a lot and if I make number of iterations then it will keep on taking 1 hour. Any suggestion?

Comment: For general matrices M1 and M2, there's probably nothing you can do.  If you know something about the sparse structure of the matrices, there may be a great deal you can do.  You might also be able to express the iterations as updates instead of resolving the full answer.  Can you provide more detail about the matrices, and about your iterations?

Comment: You're dealing with some decently big entities here. 1hr sounds okay-ish. Can it be faster? Sure. Can it be slower? Sure.

Comment: Uhm, 1.8 million times 1.8 million, assuming 64 bit variables, makes for 23 TB for `M2`, and 120 GB for `M1` and your result. Is it a logical matrix, maybe?

Comment: It is more like a tridiagonal matrix

Comment: @LucaGeretti  He said they were sparse matrices so I doubt `M1` and `M2` take up that much space.

Comment: M2 would be tiny if it were tridiagonal. Just around 5.4 million elements.

Comment: Do you mean `M1 ./ M2`? Because `M1 / M2 = M1 * inv(M2)`, but `M2` is sparse, and I guess is not invertable.

Comment: @Serg sparse does not necessarily mean *not invertible*.  In fact, there are pretty simple conditions on a tridiagonal matrix that guarantee invertibility.  Plus `M1` and `M2` aren't of the same size so he definitely means `M1 / M2`.

Comment: @ChrisA., my mistake, I didn't notice the sizes.

Answer (score 4):

A quick back-of-the-envelope calculation based on assuming some iterative method like conjugate gradient or Kaczmarz method is used, and plugging in the sizes makes me believe that an hour isn't bad.

Because of the tridiagonality the matrix that's being "inverted" (if not explicitly), both of those methods are going to take a number of instructions near "some near-unity scalar factor" times ~9000 times 1.8e6 times "the number of iterations required for convergence".  The product of the two things in quotes is probably around 50 (minimum) to around 1000 (maximum).  I didn't cherry pick these to make your math work, these are about what I'd expect from having done these.   If you assume about 1e9 instructions per second (which doesn't account much for memory access etc.) you get around 13 minutes to around 4.5 hours.

Thus, it seems in the right range for an algorithm that's exploiting sparsity.

Might be able to exploit it better yourself if you know the structure, but probably not by much.

Note, this isn't to say that 13 minutes is achievable.

Edit: One side note, I'm not sure what's being used, but I assumed iterative methods.  It's also possible that direct methods are used [(like explained here).](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/CSparse/)  These methods can be *very* efficient for sparse systems if you exploit the sparsity right.  It's very possible that Matlab is using these by default, but it's worth investigating what Matlab is doing in your case.

In my limited experience, iterative methods were usually preferred over direct methods as the size of the systems get large (yours is large.)  Our linear systems worked out to be block tridiagonal as well, as they often do in image processing.